# How to set gradiant color for stroke in shape in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape

I want create custom background and i want create this in `drawable` folder.
For this background i write below codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/gradient_center" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

but in this code i just set **sold** color for `stroke`, i want set **gradient** color for `stroke` color.

how can i it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#b5b6d2"
    android:startColor="#555994"
    android:type="linear" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```